# SFTP to download whole directory?

Tags: sftp

I'm on ubuntu.   I only have sftp access to a remote server.  The remote server disabled shell, so i can't use ssh or scp command.

Is there a way for me to recursively get the entire /var/www directory onto my localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/40281/how-do-i-get-an-entire-directory-in-sftp/40361#40361), Nautilus (the file manager in Gnome) allows you to sftp as if it were part of your filesystem. Another answer there mentions [lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru/) which has a `mirror` command.

Comment: If you use `lftp`, the `mirror` command is more appropriate, because it will recursively grab everything in the directory requested. The `mget` command is for when you want to specify multiple individual files to download.